# How do I get value from input radio in a href?

Tags: javascript, php, input, radio-button

I'm creating a card with values, example:

```
Subscribers:
Value: 5,50$
Value: 9,50$
Value: 15,50$
--------
```

Each radio input has a value and a link as a variable... so I'm passing a variable with the link to your checkout in the value... but I want that when I select a value like that, it passes the correct variable to the submit
.

```
<?php $url = 'wwww.exemplo.com/checkout1'?>
<?php $url2 = 'wwww.exemplo.com/checkout2'?>
<?php $url3 = 'wwww.exemplo.com/checkout3'?>
<?php $url4 = 'wwww.exemplo.com/checkout4'?>
<form>
<input type="radio" name="opcao" id="1" value="<?php echo $url;?>">
<input type="radio" name="opcao" id="2" value="<?php echo $url2;?>">
<input type="radio" name="opcao" id="3" value="<?php echo $url3;?>">
<input type="radio" name="opcao" id="4" value="<?php echo $url4;?>">    
<a href=""><button id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

How do I get the input value in my href

Comment: You never set `url2` or `url3` or `url4` ????

Comment: Do you have a `<form ....>` in this code?

Comment: This could be done much more cleanly with a for loop. There is also probably not a reason to assign an id attribute to these inputs in the way you are

Comment: Typo: $url is repeated, you never set $url2 etc. Check your work more carefully!

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question... I just want to know how it would be possible to do this.

Comment: I just created an example of what I was imagining, but how can I make this possible, how do I pass a variable of the input value to the submit?

Comment: @grumpyCrouton Could you explain to me how I do this with a loop? I need the selected variable link to become my HREF link

Comment: @RiggsFolly Brother, if you don't want to help, please don't answer, because your comment didn't help the question at all.

Comment: Well just useful enough for you to ADD the `<form>` and `</form>` to the code in the question :):)

Comment: @Riggsfolly I think you didn't read the question, if you read it, you'll understand what I need...

Comment: @Riggsfolly I'm not looking to find an error in this code, I want help to make this code adapt to my question friend, thanks, if you know then you answer, otherwise you don't need to answer... really thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont actually need to use an anchor tag, you can achieve a querystring and filling the $_GET array using a `<form method="get" ....>`. If that is your aim?

```
<?php
// start by using an array for your values, its more useful and extendable
$urls = ['wwww.exemplo.com/checkout1',
        'wwww.exemplo.com/checkout2',
        'wwww.exemplo.com/checkout3',
        'wwww.exemplo.com/checkout4'
        ];
# Now use a form with a GET method, 
# which will set the querystring and fill the $_GET array in the `action` form
?>
<form action="action_page.php" method="get">

<?php
foreach ( $urls as $id => $url){
    echo "<input type='radio' name='opcao' id='$id' value='$url'>";
}
?>
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

-- UPDATE

I dont think you actually want a radio button set for this, all you need is a set of anchor tags like this

```
<?php
// start by using an array for your values, its more useful and extendable
$urls = ['wwww.exemplo.com/checkout1',
        'wwww.exemplo.com/checkout2',
        'wwww.exemplo.com/checkout3',
        'wwww.exemplo.com/checkout4'
        ];
<?php
foreach ( $urls as $id => $url){
    echo "<a href='http://$url'> SITE $id</a>";
}
?>
```

---UPDATE 2

```
$urls = ['https://wwww.exemplo.com/checkout1',
        'https://wwww.exemplo.com/checkout2',
        'https://wwww.exemplo.com/checkout3',
        'https://wwww.exemplo.com/checkout4'
        ];

foreach ( $urls as $id => $url){
    echo "<a href='$url'> SITE $id</a>";

}
```

Should get you

```
<a href='https://wwww.exemplo.com/checkout1'> SITE 0</a>
<a href='https://wwww.exemplo.com/checkout2'> SITE 1</a>
<a href='https://wwww.exemplo.com/checkout3'> SITE 2</a>
<a href='https://wwww.exemplo.com/checkout4'> SITE 3</a>
```

Also, dont be afraid of `'https%3A%2F%2Fwwww.exemplo.com%2Fcheckout1'` as that is just `'https://Fwwww.exemplo.com?checkout1'` that has been URL Encoded.

Comment: It was perfect, but he's driving me towards that ending
 = action_page.php?opcao=wwww.exemplo.com%2Fcheckout2, Would you like to make it direct directly to the link

Comment: I have had another go at understanding what you actually want here, is that more like what you need

Comment: Is that a better fit with your needs?

Comment: in fact all I needed was for the value of the selected input to be passed to <a href="$url"></a> to be able to go to checkout but I don't know how to express it

Comment: Ah, your penultimate answer, it almost solved my problem, but it doesn't redirect to the $url link, it just adds it to the url that I already have, example localhost/checkout/filtros/action_page.php?opcao=wwww.exemplo.com%2Fcheckout2, what I want is for it to do this: wwww.exemplo.com/checkout2

Comment: Ok, i added the `http://` to the url, or you could add it the the entries in the Array

Comment: Or maybe it should be `https://` So maybe best to add it to the array then each could be different

Comment: how to add this array in the code, being honest I'm a student :/, if I put the url the error "/" or . and it ends up looking like this:
  action_page.php?opcao=https%3A%2F%2Fwwww.exemplo.com%2Fcheckout1  thank you very much for helping me

Comment: Do you still want the `action_page.php?opcao` part in the url?

Comment: Have a look at UPDATE 2